# porting opencv project from 32 bit machine to 64 bit machine

Tags: opencv, exe

i have done a project using OpenCV 2.3 on a 32 bit machine (win 7 32bit version) and i want to run it on 64 bit machine (win 8 64bit version) , on which opencv is not installed,  using exe file of my project. how can i do that ?
will it be enough to only copy the static libs along with the exe ?

Comment: it didn't work out @Aurelius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried, It will be enough to copy your files to new system and do not forget to add your x:\Windows\SysWOW64 some needed dll files
for example you might needed opencv_core245.dll file and you might get it from OpenCV directory

Or just another way if you were builded with MS VS to download and install your new system redistributable package from following link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632

---

Edit:

I have just found one more solution which is copying all needed dll files to same directory with .exe

Hope it helps